# Error Code: 1525. Incorrect DATE value using STR_TO_DATE

Tags: mysql

why do I receive this error:

```
Error Code: 1525. Incorrect DATE value: '01-01-2017'
```

When using this query:

```
CREATE VIEW 2017Employees AS 
    SELECT EmployeeID 
    FROM contract 
    WHERE `Start` <= STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2017','%d-%m-%y') 
    AND DueFinish>= STR_TO_DATE('31-12-2017','%d-%m-%y');
```

I thought that the function `STR_TO_DATE` converted strings to dates.

Comment: Capital `Y` for 4 char YEARS, `'01-01-2017','%d-%m-%Y'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `%Y` instead of `%y` because you are using year with four digits:

```
CREATE VIEW 2017Employees AS 
SELECT EmployeeID 
FROM contract 
WHERE `Start` <= STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2017','%d-%m-%Y') 
 AND DueFinish>= STR_TO_DATE('31-12-2017','%d-%m-%Y');
```

You can find all available format specifier with a explanation on the [documentation of `DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

- `%Y` - Year, numeric, four digits
- `%y` - Year, numeric (two digits)